# How to delete a row from SQLite database using QSqlQueryModel?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt-creator

I am trying to delete a row from QSqlQueryModel as follows:

```
void MainWindow::deleteRecord()
{
    int row_index= ui->tableView->currentIndex().row();
    model->removeRow(row_index);
}
```

But it is not working.

I tried the following as well:

```
void MainWindow::deleteRecord()
    {
        int row_index= ui->tableView->currentIndex().row();    
        if(!db_manager->delete_record(QString::number(row_no))){
            ui->appStatus->setText("Error: data deletion ...");
        } else{
            ui->appStatus->setText("Record deleted ...");
        }
    }
```

Where in db_manager, the function delete_recod(QString row_no) is:

```
bool DatabaseManager::delete_record(QString row_index)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("DELETE FROM personal_Info WHERE ref_no =  (:ref_no)");
    query.bindValue(":ref_no",row_index);
    if (!query.exec())
    {
        qDebug() << "Error" << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But also not working. In both attempts, the application doesn't crash and no SQLite errors.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

**The first approach is failing because `QSqlQueryModel` does not implement `removeRows`.** You're not checking its return value (bad! bad! bad!), which is `false`, meaning failure.

And how could it possibly implement a row removal function? Your SQL query can be literally anything, including result sets for which it does not make any sense to remove rows.

**Instead, consider using a `QSqlTableModel`** -- it or may not apply to your case, but given the form of your `DELETE` statement, I would say it does. (`QSqlTableModel` only shows the contets of one table / view).

---

**The second approach is instead possibly working already.** The fact you don't see your UI updated does not imply anything at all -- you should check the actual database contents to see if the `DELETE` statement actually worked and deleted something.

Now note that there's nothing coming from the database telling Qt to update its views. You need to set up that infrastructure. Modern databases support triggers and signalling systems (which are wrapped in Qt by `QSqlDriver::notification`), which can be used for this purposes. In other cases you msut manually trigger a refresh of your SQL model, for instance by calling `QSqlTableModel::select()`.

Comment: Btw, when I use the second solution the row gets deleted from the `TableView` and from the SQLite database too. But only if I hard coded my Primary key. I am unable to get the primary_key when selecting a row .. I am only getting the index of that selected row ..  to be precise that is exactly is my problem ..

Comment: Well, QSqlTableModel doesn't accept setQuery and it crashed as `'setQuery' is a protected member of QSqlTableModel`. I cannot execute a "select query" or a "delete query" and pass them to the model !! ... I need to be able to pass query to my model and that is why I started using `QSqlQueryModel` for the reason I can write my own query. Sadly now, I know it is "Read-only" model. !! .. problem still exist.

Comment: **What are you actually trying to do?** Not what's your attempted solution, what's your problem in the first place.

Comment: My database stores information about members of an organization. I want to be able to display my database records on GUI. Then when I select a row on the GUI, I should be able to edit or delete that record in the GUI as well as in database. That is what I am trying to do ...

Comment: Do you need to run a custom query different from a `SELECT * FROM table` to populate your UI? Do you need your UI to have read write access to the data? Which kind of write access?

Comment: yes, I need read/write access to the data. I need to be able to select columns from different tables from example. I might need to show part of a table instead of the whole table. The user might edit a database entry or delete it. I need full control over the database in term of modifying. I.e.: insert new, delete or edit a database entry.

Comment: Then go with approach #2.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. But I unable to pass the PRIMARY_KEY (which is the first column at the QTableView) when selecting a row. I am getting the row_index only. But how to tell the QTableView to return the value at the first column of the selected row ?